# Trace($A$) = Trace($A^2$) = Trace($A^3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, trace

Suppose $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real eigenvalues such that $\text{trace}(A)=\text{trace}(A^2)=\text{trace}(A^3)$. What can we conclude about the eigenvalues of A?

My attempts:

1. Considered $A$ as a diagonal matrix and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2
   ,\ldots,\lambda_n$ to be its eigenvalues. So we get $$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots\lambda_n=\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\cdots+\lambda_n^2=\lambda_1^3+\lambda_2^3+\cdots+\lambda_n^3$$
   From the first equality and using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, we could get $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots\lambda_n\leq n$. My guess is that all non-zero eigenvalues are to be 1(just an intuition). But can't proceed any further.
2. Suppose $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, then we could get trace($A^2$) = (trace($A))^2-2\det(A)$ and trace($A^3$) = (trace($A))^3-(3\det(A)\cdot\text{trace}(A))$. here also couldn't figure out a way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did the question specify the dimensions of $A$ beyond saying $n \times n$? I don't think you can conclude much if $n > 3$.

Comment: @TheoBendit No sir. It is not specified. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: (1) I'm not sure if you can glean anything more besides the first three nonleading coefficients of the characteristic polynomial and the fact the eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs. (2) Are you asking how to prove the relations? Just plug everything in.

Comment: Can be very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683472/finding-mboxtra-from-the-condition-mboxtra2-mboxtra3-mb?rq=1), can you give the source of this question?

Comment: @runway44 Thank you sir. For (2) I was able to see the mentioned results by writing down the matrix. But was clueless whether that would help my question.

Comment: @BAYMAX Thank you sir. I will check the mentioned question. My friend asked me this question. I don't exactly know the book source of the question.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ aren't necessarily real. Consider for instance any $4\times4$ real matrix $A$ whose eigenvalues are $1,-1,i,-i$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you sir. Will check that.

Comment: We can prove that all $\lambda_k=1$ if they are nonnegative (very strong assumption but anyway). Indeed, from Cauchy-Schwarz we obtain $(\lambda_1^3+\ldots+\lambda_n^3)(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n)\geq (\lambda_1^2+\ldots+\lambda_n^2)^2$. Since we have equality all $\lambda_k=1$.

Comment: @richrow Thank you so much sir. I understood the idea.

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508536